# Error in typecasting of QGraphicsItemGroup in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt4, qgraphicsview

I am trying to create a digital gates symbols ( like AND,NAND etc )  using `line`, `arc`, `circle`.  To do this I am using `QGraphicsItemGroup` also.
For example. If a symbol contains 3 lines, 2 arc and 1 circle, then I add everything in object of `QGraphicsItemGroup` and then I add this object in `scene`.

```
myGroupItem.h
class myGroupItem: public QGraphicsItemGroup 
{
      virtual void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);
}
```

myGroupItem.cpp

```
void myGroupItem ::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);
{
    auto copied_option = *option;
    copied_option.state &= ~QStyle::State_Selected;
    auto selected = option->state & QStyle::State_Selected;
    QGraphicsItemGroup::paint(painter, &copied_option, widget);
    if (selected) 
   {
      foreach (QGraphicsItem* item, _scene->selectedItems()) 
         {
            myGroupItem* inst = qgraphicsitem_cast<myGroupItem*>(item);
            if (!inst)
                continue;
            QList<QGraphicsItem*> childItems = inst->childItems();
            foreach (QGraphicsItem* chItem, childItems) 
            {
                if (myPoly* poly = dynamic_cast<myPoly*>(chItem)) 
                {
                    painter->save();
                    painter->setPen(QPen(option->palette.windowText(), 0, Qt::SolidLine));
                    painter->drawPath(poly->shape());
                    painter->restore();
                } 
              } else {
                    if (myLine* line = dynamic_cast<myLine*>(chItem)) {
                        painter->save();
                        painter->setPen(QPen(option->palette.windowText(), 0, Qt::SolidLine));
                        painter->drawPath(line->shape());
                        painter->restore();
                    } else {
                        if (myEllipse* ell = dynamic_cast<myEllipse*>(chItem)) {
                            painter->save();
                            painter->setPen(QPen(option->palette.windowText(), 0, Qt::SolidLine));
                            painter->drawPath(ell->shape());
                            painter->restore();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

myLine.h
class myLine : public QGraphicsLineItem 
{
  
}

myEllipse.h
class myEllipse : public QGraphicsEllipseItem
{
  
}

class BuildDesign()
{
    myGroupItem* groupItem = new myGroupItem();
    // accessing all lines
    myLine* line = new myLine(co-ordinate of lines);
    groupItem ->addToGroup(line);      
 
    // accessing arc
    groupItem ->addToGroup(arc); 
 
    // accessing circle 
    groupItem ->addToGroup(ellipse);                         
     
    scene->addItem(groupItem);    
}
```

This way I am creating a symbol and it is creating propely. Issue is when I want to select that
symbol and process on it.

```
 // This function will check is there any item under mouse click. If yes then call another
    // function to highlight it and if not then Refresh the scene. 
   
 void BuildDesign::SelectObject(QEvent* event)
    {
        QMouseEvent* mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
        QPointF mousePoint = _view->mapToScene(mouseEvent->pos());
        QGraphicsItem* itemUnderClick = _scene->itemAt(mousePoint, QTransform());
    
        if (!itemUnderClick)
            RefreshScene();
        else
            HighlightSelectedObject(itemUnderClick);
    }
     
 void BuildDesign::HighlightSelectedObject(QGraphicsItem* itemUnderClick)
 {  
    // QGraphicsItemGroup* gItem = qgraphicsitem_cast<QGraphicsItemGroup*>(itemUnderClick);
    myGroupItem* gItem = qgraphicsitem_cast<myGroupItem*>(itemUnderClick);
    if (gItem) {
       gItem->setSelected(true);   // this never gets executed 
    }
 }
```

Now after debugging I found that, `itemUnderClick` has some address but after type casting to `gItem` always shows address as `0x0`.
I want to execute `gItem->setSelected(true);` ( which never execute ) and further I want to use
`foreach (QGraphicsItem* currentItem, _scene->selectedItems())` and `currentItem` should be that selected symbol. But it is not happening.

Comment: Have you tried the solution here https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/54530-qgraphicsitem_cast-cannot-convert-seft-defined-types or to use dynamic_cast instead ?

Comment: @Issylin  I tried `dynamic_cast` but did not work out.

Comment: Use the link I gave you above and this link (doc) : https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsitem.html#qgraphicsitem_cast
The 1st link shows how to reimplement the type() function (see Note in the doc).

Comment: glad you succeeded, I'll post it as the official answer so it can help other people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by the doc (https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsitem.html#qgraphicsitem_cast), qgraphicsitem_cast returns nullptr if the given item is not of type T, OR, if it cannot deduce its type.

The last case is the cause of your issue here, you have to reimplement the type() function for each custom QGraphicsItem subclass.

The following link shows how to do this, https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/54530-qgraphicsitem_cast-cannot-convert-seft-defined-types , see the answer of Santosh Reddy.